# Combining these two Java streams into one

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

is there a possibility to combine the two streams in the method into one, so there is only one return statement line? The method should calculate the sum of each **column** in the given two dimensional double array, insignificant which structure the array has, but the array has at least one element, and non null rows are allowed. Thanks a lot.

```java
public static double[] sumUpCols(double[][] x) {
    double[][] a = Stream.of(x).sorted((a0, a1) -> a1.length - a0.length).toArray(double[][]::new);
    return IntStream.range(0, a[0].length).mapToDouble(i -> IntStream.range(0, a.length).mapToDouble(j -> i < a[j].length ? a[j][i] : 0.0).sum()).toArray();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    double[][] x = { { 1 }, { 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 }, { 5, 2 } };
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sumUpCols(x)));
}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to zip streams together?

Comment: Hello @AndyTurner, yes, that's the right term.

Comment: Before you try merging streams and stuff like that, how about you fix the code so it won't crash and die? --- Try input `{ { 1 }, { 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 }, { 2, 3 } }` and you get `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 2 out of bounds for length 2`. --- Try input `{ { 1 }, { 2 } }` and you get `[1.0]`, but that should be `[3.0]`. --- Then perhaps the different code that actually works might already be a single stream, who knows?

Comment: Hello @Andreas, sorry for that, I've edited and fixed the code.

Comment: With that new code, what is the purpose of sorting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a boxed trial without sorting the array by converting it to a map where the column index is the key and the value is the sum of the column:

```
Collection<Double> values = Arrays.stream(x)
      .flatMap(b -> IntStream.range(0, b.length)
                    .mapToObj(i -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<Integer, Double>(i, b[i])))
      .collect(groupingBy(e -> e.getKey(), summingDouble(v -> v.getValue())))
      .values();
```

Comment: Thanks! One liner: `return Arrays.stream(x).flatMap(b -> IntStream.range(0, b.length).mapToObj(i -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<Integer, Double>(i, b[i]))).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e.getKey(), Collectors.summingDouble(v -> v.getValue()))).values().stream().mapToDouble(d -> d).toArray();`

Answer (score 1):

```
public static double[] sumUpCols(double[][] x) {
     // return Stream.of(x).mapToDouble((double[] row) -> DoubleStream.of(row).sum()).toArray();

     return Stream.of(x)
            .sorted((a0, a1) -> a1.length - a0.length)
            .reduce((double[] left, double[] right) -> {
                IntStream.range(0, right.length).forEach(i -> left[i] += right[i]);
                return left;
    }).get();
}
```

Comment: I've tried to calculate the columns sum, not the rows sum.

Comment: The result for this solution mismatch to that in the question as pointed out by @unknown_dcba . Besides, you could have simplified this to `return Stream.of(x)
                .mapToDouble((double[] row) -> DoubleStream.of(row).sum())
                .toArray();`

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly a single stream traversal, yet a slightly better approach could be to identify the max length possible for a nested array. Then iterate using it as indexes and

```
public static double[] sumUpColumns(double[][] x) {
    return IntStream.range(0, Stream.of(x).mapToInt(a -> a.length).max().orElse(0))
            .mapToDouble(i -> Arrays.stream(x)
                    .mapToDouble(item -> i < item.length ? item[i] : 0.0)
                    .sum())
            .toArray();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*lambda with reduction — without the use of* `map`, `flatMap` *or an additional* `IntStream`

```
public static double[] sumUpCols(double[][] x) {
  double[][] sum = new double[][] { {0}, {} };
  return( Stream.of( x ).reduce( (a1, a2) -> {
    for( int i = 0; i < a1.length || i < a2.length; i++ ) {
      sum[0] = Arrays.copyOf( sum[0], i + 1 );
      sum[0][i] = 0;
      try {
        sum[0][i] += a1[i];
      }
      catch( ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ex ) {}  // ignored
      try {
        sum[0][i] += a2[i];
      }
      catch( ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ex ) {}  // ignored
    }
    return sum[0];
  } ).get() );
}
```

enlarges the result-array dynamically
can handle empty rows too

gets: `[12.0, 10.0, 6.0]`